# Memory allocation of struct in C++

Tags: struct

My struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct KeypointSt {
    float row, col;             
    float scale, ori;           
    unsigned char *descrip;     /* Vector of descriptor values */
    struct KeypointSt *next;    
} *Keypoint;
```

The following is a part of a code in C. How can I translate it to C++, considering allocation and de-allocation of heap.

```
Keypoint k, keys = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    /* Allocate memory for the keypoint. */
    k = (Keypoint) malloc(sizeof(struct KeypointSt));
    k->next = keys;
    keys = k;
    k->descrip = malloc(len);

    for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        k->descrip[j] = (unsigned char) val;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, technically it's already c++. you want to use `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. PLease read the [About] page soon. Can you not create a constructor for the structure that ensures that all members are initialized (`row`, `col`, `scale` and `ori` are not set at the moment, so you get random data stored in those)? It might be better to use `memset()` instead of the `for (j = 0; ...)` loop.  It isn't clear whether `len` should be stored in the structure. You can use `new` to allocate the memory.

Comment: I want to use new and delete for the above code. I used new and delete, but it gives me heap corruption! please rewrite the code in the form of c++.

Comment: new/delete operate on objects. So, you need to convert C style structures to C++ classes and derive objects from them. To give an example of new and malloc usage, please refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/

Comment: @Isk: In C++, `struct`s are the same as `class`es except that the default visibility is `public`. `new` and `delete` should have no problems with `struct`s.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of converting to C++ is:

```
#include <cstring>  // memset()

typedef struct KeypointSt
{
    float row, col;             
    float scale, ori;
    size_t len;         
    unsigned char *descrip;     /* Vector of descriptor values */
    KeypointSt *next;
    KeypointSt(int p_len, int p_val) : row(0.0), col(0.0), scale(0.0),
                                       ori(0.0), len(p_len),
                                       descrip(new unsigned char[len]), next(0)
    { memset(descrip, len, p_val); }
    ~KeypointSt() { delete descrip; }
} *Keypoint;

extern KeypointSt *init_keypoints(size_t num, size_t len, unsigned char val);
extern void        free_keypoints(KeypointSt *list);

KeypointSt *init_keypoints(size_t num, size_t len, unsigned char val)
{
    KeypointSt *keys = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        /* Allocate memory for the keypoint. */
        KeypointSt *k = new KeypointSt(len, val);
        k->next = keys;
        keys = k;
    }
    return keys;
}

void free_keypoints(KeypointSt *list)
{
    while (list != 0)
    {
        KeypointSt *next = list->next;
        delete list;
        list = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    KeypointSt *keys = init_keypoints(4, 5, 6);
    free_keypoints(keys);
    return 0;
}
```

The only reason I've kept the `typedef` in place is because you have existing code; the C++ code would be better using `KeypointSt *` everywhere — or renaming the structure tag to `Keypoint` and using `Keypoint *` in place of your original `Keypoint`.  I don't like non-opaque types where the `typedef` conceals a pointer.  If I see a declaration `XYZ xyz;`, and it is a structure or class type, I expect to use `xyz.pqr` and not `xyz->pqr`.

We can debate code layout of the constructor code, the absence of a default constructor (no arrays), and the absence of a copy constructor and an assignment operator (both needed because of the allocation for `descrip`).  The code of `init_keypoints()` is not exception safe; a memory allocation failure will leak memory. Fixing that is left as an exercise (it isn't very hard, I think, but I don't claim exception-handling expertise).  I've not attempted to consider any extra requirements imposed by C++11.  Simply translating from C to C++ is 'easy' until you look at the extra demands that C++ makes — demands that make your life easier in the long run, but at a short-term cost in pain.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, May I have your email address to send you my code.